# How To add the JDE To Eclipse Plugin

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have used NetBeans IDE,I installed the NetBeans plugin for BB,and then it will detect the List of JDE's presently installed in the System and i can use it in NetBeans.

Similarly i want to know how to add the Blackberry JDE to Eclipse IDE.It always come with Inbuit JDE 4.5 and what can be done to add new JDE's(5.0 ,6.0 etc) to the Eclipse IDE.I have Eclipse 1.0.67 version,

Besides in the Form ,is it possible,i have also downloaded Eclipse 1.1.s

Do i want to download new plugin similar to netbeans ,can u explain in detail?

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Comment: Hello ,is my question wrong?Still no replies?

Answer (score 2):

In the Help menu, choose Install New Software. In the resulting dialog, click the Add... button. In the Location field add this url: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/3.6/java/. You don't need to add a name, Eclipse will resolve it for you. Once it's added there is a wait while Eclipse fetches data from that url. Expand BlackBerry Java Plug-in Category once it loads, and the available SDKs will be there. Installing any of those will configure Eclipse with the JDE you want.